# Weird issue with Tomcat and localhost

Tags: spring-mvc, ip, localhost, tomcat8

So this is the issue. I have a spring mvc application. When I start the application in Intellij, tomcat starts(http://localhost:8080/home) but I eventually get a message that the site cannot be reached. The ip address(192.168.251.49) its trying resolve is not my localhost. If I use my localhost ip(192.168.2.19) it works, but I get an notification that the site is not secure. This started last week, I was working from home, so I was connected to work via a VPN, and I was remoting into my work pc. Then on my home pc I had started up this app, then after closing my connection to work this problem started happening.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: check the  1. tomcat 8 and java version ..most of the times the issues i faced ( both on linux and windows ) were w.r.t tomcat 8 version and java mismatch  . 2.  try with tomcat7 and java 7 combination..its a sure shot success !

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But that's not it. It was working fine up until I connected to the vpn.